# Passing information down for system() in multi-thread program

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, popen

I have a message generated by caller of `exec()` or `system()` or `popen()`, and want to pass it to the child process. Change env is one way, but in multi-thread program, changing env by `putenv()` or `setenv()` is not safe. I am not allowed to pass it by the `argv` of the child process.

Writing something to some file is one choice, but how can we identify one particular message is passed from which parent and intended to which child? One way is to append parent pid to the message, and the child can find message with ppid matching. But when multiple threads call `popen()`, there will be several message with the same pid.

Comment: What language do you use?  I guess C?  The answer depends on the language: for instance, Python has an `env` parameter to `popen()`…

Answer (score 0):

I am not a specialist, but here is an idea:

Shells allow you to use "temporary" environment variables.  For instance, you can do (in zsh):

```
% MSG="Hello" my_prog
% echo $MSG

%
```

Maybe you could do something like this?  maybe this would involve running your command in a sub-shell?

Answer (score 0):

popen() is probably your friend here. I would suggest using locking to prevent multiple threads from writing down the pipe at once, and tag your messages with thread id information.